# Deploy Azure-targeted SSDT project to local SQL Server Instance?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

It is possible/valid to deploy an SSDT project which targets SQL Azure to my local instance of SQL Server for local development purposes?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Make sure your local version is the latest SQL Server version or vNext preview.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [How to: Build and Deploy to a Local Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-build-and-deploy-to-a-local-database?view=sql-server-2017) and as was pointed out, make sure the the SQL Server Express Local Database Runtime is the latest.

> Microsoft SQL Server 20XX provides a local on-demand server instance, called SQL Server Express Local Database Runtime, which is activated when you debug a SQL Server Database project. This local server instance can be used as a sandbox for building, testing and debugging your project. It is independent of any of your installed SQL Server instances, and is not accessible outside SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). Such an arrangement is ideal for developers who have limited or no access to production databases, but would like to test their projects locally before authorized personnel will deploy them to production. In addition, when you are developing a database solution for SQL Azure, you can utilize the convenience provided by this local server to develop and test your database project locally, before deploying it to the cloud.